# Search Python list and return 2 or more of the same character

Tags: python, list

I've just started to learn Python and I'm creating the game Hangman. I've got the basic functionality down. I have a list containing the words and they're randomly selected. I have an input for the user to guess letters and check it against the list that the word is split into, I have another list that the correctly guessed letters are put into at the position they are in the randomly selected word.

The problem I am having is that if the word has a letter within it more than once, it will only find the first letter and add that. How would I go about looking for all instances of a letter and adding them?

This is the code I'm using to map guessed letters against the randomly selected word.

```
if user_input in choose_word:
    print "Good guess!"
    print trys_remaining, "trys remaining!"
    word_index = letter_list.index(user_input)
    correct_letters[word_index] = user_input
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop over all matching indices:

```
for word_index, letter in enumerate(letter_list):
    if letter == user_input:
        correct_letters[word_index] = user_input
```

*Note:* If the loop would be `for letter in letter_list:` you would only iterate over letters but won't get the corresponding index. The `enumerate()` function allows to get the index at the same time.
See also the [enumerate documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: That's pretty perfect. Maybe add case sensitivity by `lower`-ing `user_input` and `letter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
correct_letters = [letter if user_input == letter else correct
                   for (correct, letter) in zip(correct_letters, letter_list)]
```

Note that this will create a new `correct_letters` list, instead 
of modifying the original one.